# Rails connecting to Java desktop?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets

I thought of an Web application made in Ruby on Rails (made up the idea just to learn Ruby while working on it). The Web application allows me to receive information from the Java desktop application. So for example.. (just an example) let's say that the desktop application holds a list of torrents currently being downloaded, a user logs in to the web application and sees hes current downloading list BUT also he can interact with it, add new torrents, delete torrents (AJAX refreshing this panel). My idea is ofcourse that the web application is being used by more then 1 user. So here is my question.. How to handle this? I am new to connections between apps. I considered few options like:

1. Socket - here comes another question then... how to handle such thing. I imagine it like this, user logs in he makes a request to the desktop app to gather information simply sending some information over socket (command) and starts listening to socket but here's the problem, what happens when it will have multiple requests listening to the port? I thought of an application scoped thread listening and assigning incoming data to a session that requested it. Is it even possible?
2. Database - wouldn't it be a heavy solution for the database? Desktop app would have to delete the whole content that is assigned to a current user account and insert it again with fresh data. What if i had like 1000 users. (1000 users is dream but still i would feel better with finding a solution that is... good)
3. RMI - i know there is such thing in Java web applications and this is the last option i would choose since i want to learn Ruby on Rails badly.
4. ? any other options?

Is it even possible?

Comment: 1000 users is nothing for a database, assuming there are maybe 15 torrents per user that's just 15000 records. It's difficult to say what exactly would be the best solution, there are programs like SABnzbd that run in the background and the UI is a local web interface. Where would this desktop app run? What is the server doing? After all, assume you have some Rails web server, then any desktop app can just use a common web api interface, that's no persistent connection, but that may not be mandatory for your use case.

Comment: Web API? Doesn't it work like... Desktop Application can get info from web application? Or it can actually SEND information through Web API to the Web application? Desktop app would run on users computer and yes the server would be Rails Web Server. Please excuse my lack of knowledge about it. Web API is definetly something i'll have a look into soon after you told me about it :)

Comment: @user3296521: You need to find a mentor build this application in pair or you can start building it and then post specific issues that you encounter.